# create a gitlab ci service

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

Its possible create CI service for gitlab? what API I use for that? think of a service like https://styleci.io/, this is executed automatically in every commit? the nature of the service what we want create is a "approval system", let say for each pull request must have the approve of 2 QA and 2 Developers, currently in gitlab I cant specify roles of approve, or i dont know how do that, also i dont know if exist some project than can do that... its a internal project for the company, nothing fancy, but we really need it.